# Rounded corners (border-radius) does not work as expected on Safari 8 iPad Mini

Tags: html, css, ipad-mini

The first three items work as expected, but the others are not - please check the attached picture.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shareefhiasat/5d4gzzwk/)

HTML:

```
<div class="citation-links">
<a href="linkout" target="_blank" class="ref-link ui-link">CrossRef</a>
<a href="linkout" target="_blank" class="ref-link ui-link">PubMed</a>
<a href="linkout" target="_blank" class="ref-link ui-link">CAS</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ref-link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0em .75em .15em;
  margin: 0 .25em 0;
  color: #FFF !important;
  background-color: #4E4E4E;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: .75em;
  position: relative;
  top: -.15em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1000px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the rounded corners look OK in your image for references 4 & 5, but the white text is missing. Please can you elaborate on what the issue is i.e. what are you expecting them to look like?

Comment: The problem is that the white text does not appear inside the anchor.(in the image the div elements on the right are shows the issue)

Comment: here is a jsfiddle demo for the problem but i could not simulate the safari enging ! http://jsfiddle.net/shareefhiasat/5d4gzzwk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine has found a solution to this issue. 
What was causing this issue is the below *styles*:

```
position: relative;
top: -.15em;
```

Removing the above two styles made it working perfectly.